# Need info regarding Web UI testing tool

Tags: asp.net

i have developed my website in VS2010. is there any tool freely available which can help me to test my website with different version of different browser. i saw some time my site UI display ok in my browser but when it run in other machine with big screen then UI getting distorted. so i need some tool which show me how UI look with different screen size and resolution with different browser with different version all in one......please help me with info. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) provides a bunch of DLLs that you can use to write your own automated tests against several browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc). This, however, is not a complete solution since there are limitations as to the kinds of things that you can do - some browsers have better support than others.

You'd need to install all the different browsers that you want to test on the same machine where you are running your tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing web sites professionally I'd suggest getting a nice large screen (they're cheap nowadays) and installing all of the major web browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, etc.). Then, in each browser go to their extensions/plugin and look for a resize extension. This will provide you with a drop down menu to easily resize the browser to standard screen sizes or any other size you like.

I typically choose a "master" browser and do my work in that. Then, after I've completed a section/page/area I check it in the other browsers to confirm it works.

Avoiding CSS padding combined with width/height can help as some older browsers use a different box model. Margin can be safer but you should read up on box models if you're doing any CSS development.